# Connect to affiliatewindow

Tags: c#, asp.net, soap, wsdl

I try to connect to affiliatewindow, (http://v3.core.com.productserve.com/ProductServeService.wsdl) to get categories but when i try to connect i get this: "Additional information: Authentication Failed"

I have this:

```
var A = new ApiService
{
    UserAuthenticationValue = new UserAuthentication {sApiKey = "xxxxx"}
};

var r = new getCategoryTree {iCategoryId = 0};
var result = A.getCategoryTree(r);
```

But when i contact the affiliatewindow support, they tell me that they dont know how to do in .NET. They say something about API_USERNAME, API_PASSWORD and API_KEY. But where should i put this?

So, how can i connect to affiliatewindow?

**UPDATE:**  I used the wrong APiKey.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650699/how-do-i-send-api-credentials-and-username-password-with-net-parse-com-ph

Comment: Thanx, but i can't find any answer on my question. ApiService is a Web References to affiliatewindow.